# Number of matrices with no repeated columns or rows

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics

If you consider all $m$ by $n$ matrices with entries that are either $0$ or $1$, there are ${2^{n} \choose m}$ with no repeated rows (up to row permutation) and ${2^{m} \choose n}$ with no repeated columns (up to column permutation).  Is it possible to get an explicit estimate for how many there are with neither any repeated rows nor columns (up to either row or column permutation)?  I am interested in the case where $m$ is large and $m \leq n \leq m^2$.

[Extended version of a previous unanswered [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680894/number-of-matrices-with-no-repeated-columns-or-rows) question ]

Comment: Almost all matrices of these dimensions have no repeated rows or columns (the probability that two rows are the same is bounded by $\binom m2 2^{-n}$ and the probability that two columns are the same is at most $\binom n2 2^{-m}$. So a good estimate is $2^{nm}$.

Comment: Continuing Anthony's comment, almost none of them have any symmetries either (slightly harder to prove) so to allow for row and column permutations asymptotically just divide my $m!\,n!$.

Comment: The problem of counting these matrices up to row and column permutations is solved in
I. M. Gessel and J. Li, Enumeration of point-determining graphs, J. Combinatorial Theory Ser. A 118 (2011), 591-612, available online at http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0042. (In the paper they are called 
"semi-point-determining bicolored graphs".) Of course, as in most unlabeled graphical enumeration problems, the formula is not simple, and might not be so helpful in deriving an asymptotic formula.
 
The numbers in Richard's formula are sequence [A181230](http://oeis.org/A181230) in the OEIS.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(m,n)$ denote the number of matrices being counted (not up to row
and column permutation). We can try to compute $f(m,n)$ by
Inclusion-Exclusion, allowing the rows to be distinct and sieving out
the possible ways in which columns can be equal. This is just Möbius
inversion on the lattice $\Pi_n$ of partitions of an $n$-element
set. Plugging into the techniques of *Enumerative Combinatorics*,
vol. 2, Section 5.1, gives
  $$ F(x,y):=\sum_{m,n\geq 0} f(m,n)\frac{x^m}{m!}\frac{y^n}{n!} =
      \sum_{n\geq 0}(1+x)^{2^n}\frac{(\log(1+y))^n}{n!}. $$
It is curious that $F(x,y)=F(y,x)$. It shouldn't be difficult to get
some good estimates for $f(m,n)$ from $F(x,y)$.

It seems more difficult to count the matrices up to row
and column permutations because even if all the rows are distinct and
all the columns are distinct, a matrix can still be fixed by a
nontrivial permutation of rows and columns.

Comment: Is the accepted answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680894/number-of-matrices-with-no-repeated-columns-or-rows actually correct?